# Creating a random, undirected, weighted, complete graph

Tags: c++, graph

so I've written the whole algorithm actually, but for some reason it doesn't work properly. Please note that I'm a beginner and code is just a sample in phase of testing, I will take care of every stylistic detail etc. later.

Here's the code in cpp file:

```
#include "OK.hpp"
using namespace std;

Graph::Graph(int v)  //constructor
{
    this->g_size=v;
    adjacjency_matrix=new int*[g_size];
    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++)
    {
        adjacjency_matrix[i]=new int[g_size];
        for(int j=0;j<g_size;j++)
        {
            adjacjency_matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

void Graph::add_edges()
{
    int helper[g_size];

    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++)  //fills the array in increasing order
    {
        helper[i]=i;
    }

    for (int i=g_size-1;i>0;i--) //shuffle the array
    {
        int j=rand() & i;
        int tmp=helper[i];
        helper[i]=helper[j];
        helper[j]=tmp;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++)  //vector  which will later contain a present degree of each vertic
    {
        degree.push_back(0);
    }

    for (int i=1;i<g_size;i++)//fills matrix so it contains a simple pathed graph. 
    {                          // thanks to this, the graph will be complete
        int j=rand() % 100+1;
        adjacjency_matrix[helper[i-1]][helper[i]]=j;
        adjacjency_matrix[helper[i]][helper[i-1]]=j;
        degree[helper[i]]++;
        degree[helper[i-1]]++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++){  //prints the graph, irrelevant
        for(int j=0;j<g_size;j++){
            if(adjacjency_matrix[i][j]!=0 && adjacjency_matrix[j][i]!=0) cout<<i<<"\t"<<j<<"\t"<<adjacjency_matrix[i][j]<<"\t"<<degree[i]<<endl;
        }
    }

    vector<int> degree_should; //creates a vector which will contain desired degree of each vertic
    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++)
    {
        degree_should.push_back(0);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++) //fills vector with random, desired degrees for each vertic
    {
        if(degree[i]>1)  //two vertices which previously had degree=1 still have same degree
        {
            int j=rand() % 6+1;
            degree_should[i]=j;
        }
        else
            degree_should[i]=1;
    }

    int size_g=g_size-1;
    vector<int> vertices_to_connect; //this will be needed below

    for(int i=0;i<g_size;i++) //adds randomly weighted edges between vertic i and a random vertic
    {
        if(degree[i]>1 && (degree_should[i]!=degree[i])) //for every vertic with degree higher than 1 and
        {                                                // different than desired one
            while(degree_should[i]!=degree[i]) 
            {
                int vertic= rand() & size_g; 
                cout<<vertic<<endl;
                int weight= rand() % 100+1;
                if(degree_should[i]>2)  //if desired degree is bigger than 2
                {
                    if(degree[i]<degree_should[i] && degree[vertic]<degree_should[vertic]) //this prevent
                    {                                      //adding edges to vertices which already has
                    adjacjency_matrix[i][vertic]=weight;   //desired degree
                    adjacjency_matrix[vertic][i]=weight;
                    degree[vertic]++;
                    degree[i]++;
                    }
                    else continue; 
                }
                if(degree_should[i]==1)//previous if's guarantee that only vertices of degree=2 might 
                {                                                  //have desired degree=1
                     if(degree[vertic]<degree_should[vertic]) //as before
                     {
                        for(int j=0;j<g_size;j++)
                        {
                            if(adjacjency_matrix[i][j]!=0 && adjacjency_matrix[j][i]!=0)
                            {
                                adjacjency_matrix[i][j]=0;     //this if deletes edges between vertic 
                                adjacjency_matrix[j][i]=0;     //(which has a degree=2 and a desired 
                                degree[i]--;                   //degree=1) and adjacent vertices
                                degree[j]--;
                                vertices_to_connect.push_back(j);  
                            }
                        }
                        int w=rand() % 100+1;    //this part below connects vertices which were adjacjent
                        int x=vertices_to_connect[1];    //to a vertic with desired degree=1
                        int y=vertices_to_connect[0];
                        vertices_to_connect.pop_back();
                        vertices_to_connect.pop_back();
                        adjacjency_matrix[x][y]=w;
                        adjacjency_matrix[y][x]=w;  
                        degree[x]++;
                        degree[y]++;
                        adjacjency_matrix[i][vertic]=weight;  //creates an edge between vertic of desired
                        adjacjency_matrix[vertic][i]=weight;  //degree=1 and a random vertic generated
                        degree[vertic]++;                      //at the beggining of while
                        degree[i]++;
                     }
                     else continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Before you ask, yes I used srand(time((NULL)) in main. However I noticed that random vertices created at the beginning of while loop are always similar. It's always numbers 1-10 , 30-39, 60-69, 90-99. I guess this may be the reason the loop never ends because there is no way for every vertic to have it's desired degree. Does anyone see any solution? Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

EDIT: problem solved by substituting rand() function with  solution.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to help, unfortunately.  You should add some logging to assist you in figuring out why you aren't getting the randomness you expect.  Trace the random numbers from `rand()` all the way to `add_edges` and see where the problem lies.  Also, under what conditions would `degree_should[i]!=degree[i]` cause an infinite loop?  Are you structuring the random data such that the while loop will always finish?  Basically -- please do some debugging and help us help you by giving more info.

Comment: You may want to use the `<random>` header as it includes better random number features: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915020/efficient-random-number-generation-with-c11-random

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 I thought that because of the fact that random vertices are usually the same, for some `i` there will may not exist `vertic` which could create more edges. However this will probably be solved by repearing the randomisation of vertices. Thanks for your advices, i will definitely do some debugging and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 So I changed rand function into <random> sollution and it helped. However another issue occured. At some point for ending value of `i`, loop couldn't find a veritc with `degree_should` lower than the actual vertic `degree`. Is there anyway i can optimalize my code? I know there had to be few vertices with `degree` lower than desired but finding such vertic may take a lot of time. Or maybe you know any other way to initialize a random graph generator?